# make delayed mousedown event

Tags: c#, winforms, mousedown

I have a datagridview which cells has a click event. The cells also have the following mouseDown event:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 1)
{
    string[] filesToDrag = 
    {
        "c:/install.log"
    };

    gridOperations.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, filesToDrag), DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

whenever I try to click a cell, the mousedown event instantly fires and tries  to drag the cell. How can I make the mousedown event fire only if user has holded mouse down for 1 second for example? Thanks!

Comment: I tend to do this not by time, but by distance the pointer has moved while the button is held.

Comment: @lc. I like this idea. A sort of inertia-drag'n'drop?

Comment: @J.Steen Basically. I save state when the button is pressed and check the pointer is moved past a certain threshold distance (in `OnMouseMove`) As I understand it this is how most applications respond and it feels natural. Try dragging something on this page, for example, and see how the cursor changes.

Comment: @lc. Oh yeah. Weirdly natural. I must remember this UX "pattern".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to do this is not by time but to trigger it when the user moved the mouse enough.  The universal measure for "moved enough" in Windows is the double-click size.  Implement the CellMouseDown/Move event handlers, similar to this:

```
    private Point mouseDownPos;

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        mouseDownPos = e.Location;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left) {
            if (Math.Abs(e.X - mouseDownPos.X) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width ||
                Math.Abs(e.Y - mouseDownPos.Y) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height) {
                // Start dragging
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe SystemInformation.DragSize would be the better choice.